# Как обрезать линию в svg?

Tags: html, svg, графика

Нарисован прямоугольный треугольник и хочется сделать из линии высоту.

Линия заходит за сторону.

Подскажите как её обрезать ?

```html
<svg height="210" width="500" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 500 210">
  <polygon points="120,15 290,170 120,170" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></polygon>
<line x1="250" y1="10" x2="120" y2="170" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></line>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обернуть оба элемента в группу и сдвинуть влево и так же поправить viewBox и получается вот это

```html
<svg height="150" width="160" viewBox="0 0 160 150">
  <g transform="translate(-120,-14)">
  <polygon points="120,15 290,170 120,170" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></polygon>
<line x1="285" y1="10" x2="115" y2="170" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
  </g>
</svg>
```